# Can we know http calls calling by an application

Tags: http, web-applications

For example there is a web app called ababab.com , for their purpose they are calling few http requests from inside their application.

As a end user I can able to see what requets/urls going to ababab.com but is there any way to know what http calls they are making in inside of their application.

Thanks